# how do i get rid of win10 and replace with ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

I wish to completely remove the win10 OS from my computer & replace it with Ubuntu is this possible? and how do I do it?

please assume that I need step by step.

Answer (score 0):

There is plenty of help available, but I'll give you a run-down.

Check what type of BIOS you have. If you have a brand new Windows 8/8.1/10 shipped computer you most likely have UEFI. If you have an older device it most likely will be a Legacy device.

Create a linux live CD/USB. If you are under a UEFI system, install rufus in Windows and format your USB with UEFI GPT Partition tables, FAT32, and add the Ubuntu disk image.

If you are under a Legacy system, let rufus format the USB to default and select the disk image.

Make sure the disk image you downloaded corresponds to your processor type. If your processor is 64-bit, download the amd64 image. If your process is 32-bit, download the 32-bit image.

If you are under UEFI, you will have to hold shift and click restart under Windows. A recovery Window will load. Navigate to "Use a Device", and your computer will reboot. On the boot option menu, select your USB. It will most likely have the hardware name- Sandisk for a Sandisk usb, etc.

If you are under Legacy, press F2, F8, F11, Del, etc. depending on your motherboard, for boot options. Boot from your usb.

Ubuntu should boot. Select "Install now". There will be 3 options. Select "Replace Windows 10 with Ubuntu". Follow the prompts, and you should be fine.